# Is there any way to Create Pull request to bitbucket git repository using intelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea, bitbucket, pull-request, bitbucket-server

I have a git repository in bitbucket, is there any way to create a pull request using IntelliJ IDEA instead of doing it through web?

I found that this can be done from within IntelliJ for a github repository. But have not found anything similar for Bitbucket.

Answer (score 10):

***Summary: Currently not supported***
(Details below)

This has just been confirmed. I raised a support ticket to ask about this and received a reply:

[image]

If you are interested in this feature, please vote for 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88198

---

Looking at [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2011/08/work-with-bitbucket-from-your-favorite-ide-with-a-plugin-by-atlassian/) blog post, it appears that Bitbucket integration is not a plugin native to Intellij IDEA:

> And the Atlassian team just did that! A new Bitbucket plugin is now
>   available in our repository that offers a simple and well-working
>   integration allowing you to:
>
> - checkout your existing Bitbucket repository and auto-open it as a project, and
> - share a project on Bitbucket instantly, without leaving the IDE.

The Atlassian plugin mentioned above is [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?pycharm&id=6207), but it has not been updated since 2013 and even if it works for recent versions of Intellij, it does not have the functionality you are looking for.

---

Looking at other requests to add support to Intellij IDEA for 'Support Bitbucket functionality X', there hasn't been much traction. Examples:

[Bitbucket Issue Trackers Integration](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-72901) <sup>(Created Aug, 2011)</sup>

[Bitbucket Snippets support](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146851) <sup>(Create Oct, 2015)</sup>

That would imply that the 'Bitbucket pull requests' functionality is unlikely to be supported in Intellij IDEA anytime soon.

---

There is another Jetbrains product, for code review, called [Upsource](https://www.jetbrains.com/upsource/) but that does not have it either. From [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/upsource/) jetbrains blog post:

> Despite the pros listed above, there are still a few things missing
>   that I am waiting for:
>
> - Swift and Obj-C support (we are a mobile app development company and iOS app development is a large part of our services).
> - More valuable code review analytics (with over 50 projects configured it is hard to track overall code review performance).
> - ***Support for Bitbucket pull requests (only GitHub is currently supported)***.

Answer (score 6):

The "Bitbucket Linky" plugin for IDEA supports this, binding it to Cmd+Shift+X P on Mac and Ctrl+Shift+X P on Windows.

Comment: Actually I am currently using this plugin. But I need something like github pull request creator. It will not redirect to the site. It can create a pull request without going to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the problem is in BitBucket API which doesn't expose pull request information, not in JetBrains IDE itself. Other projects like magit suffer from this too.

There's [an issue](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-5814) on this topic at BitBucket, one can vote for it.

Comment: Then how does the VSCode plugin do it?  Probably with the API, which does exist https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pullrequests

Answer (score -1):

Atlassian
now build a plugin for integration with IntelliJ idea
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1221851/integration-with-jetbrains-ides?hosting=cloud&tab=overview

Comment: This is not developped by Atlassian and `This partner has not completed the Security Self-Assessment Program.`

Comment: Not developed by Atlassian, and not free.